# Why am I getting this exception with ActiveRecord (not in rails) using autoincrement

Tags: ruby, activerecord

Sorry for the dumb question but I've googled quite a bit and can't seem to figure out what the problem I'm even having actually is.
I'm trying to insert into a(n empty) table and getting the following:

```
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/attribute_assignment.rb:69:in `assign_attributes': undefined method `stringify_keys' for "A":String (NoMethodError)
```

I query another table for the "ticker" field and calculate the growth_rate for that ticker and then try to insert those values into fast_growers. Here's the relevant code:

```
Tickers.all.each do |t|
  ticker = t.ticker
  #get ticker data from interwebs and parse with Nokogiri
  #calculate growth_rate
  FastGrowers.create(ticker, growth_rate)
end
```

If anyone could shed some light on what's happening I would greatly appreciate it.

Thanks!

Comment: You passing a string where you should be passing a hash.

Comment: @Ramy, is your model name `Tickers` or `Ticker`, singular vs. plural?

Comment: @vinodadhikary Tickers

Comment: @Ramy, out of bounds?  Out of context to this question but suggest sticking to rails convention: model names should be singular.

Comment: @Ramy, Sorry, got sidetracked by your model naming.  Please post your model definition if it's possible; don't need to see functions beyond what the question asks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message suggests that your are not passing the correct types of arguments to the assign_attributes method (which is used to set the attributes on an ActiveRecord object, before it saves them to the database). Does FastGrowers inherit from ActiveRecord? If so, have you overriden the FastGrowers.create method to take a Tickers object? I suspect that what you want is probably FastGrowers.create(:ticker => ticker, :growth_rate => growth_rate), but can't be sure from the snippet above.

Hope this helps/